# Como colocar um Vídeo dentro de um Texto com CSS? É possível colocar um Vídeo como background de texto?

Tags: css, css3, vídeo, background, html5-video

Vi esse efeito e estou tentando colocar em um projeto, mas não sei como colocar um Vídeo dentro de Texto, só consegui com imagens...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui coloquei uma imagem como fundo do texto, **mas como eu faço para colocar um vídeo como `background` de um texto?**

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}
h1 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 100px;
    color: transparent; 
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background: url(https://unsplash.it/140/80) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>VÍDEO</h1>
```

**OBS:** Preciso que seja um **VÍDEO** e não um .GIF animado!

Comment: Possivelmente relacionado: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-knockout-text-with-looping-video/

Comment: @Pedro legal o link, pq não aproveita para bolar uma resposta e trazer esse conteúdo aqui pro site tb?

Comment: @Pedro jovem caso te interesse no assunto, consegui uma solução interessante que é um pouco mais simples que essa do link que vc postou abs

Answer (score 4):

Como não obtive resposta vou postar um resultado que consegui usando `mix-blend-mode` https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode

> A propriedade `mix-blend-mode` descreve como um elemento de conteúdo deve ser mesclado com os elementos abaixo dele no `background`.

No caso a valor `lighten` significa que a cor preta quando está sobre um fundo branco o preto fica transparente, logo como tenho um texto com `color:black`, sobre um fundo com `background-color:white` o que for `black` fica *transparente* possibilitando ver o elemento `video` que está por traz.

Segue o exemplo de como ficou o resultado:

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container-video {
 margin: auto;
 width: 75vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.container-video video {
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  position: absolute;
}

.text {
 font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 10vw;
  font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;

 color: black;
 mix-blend-mode: lighten;
 background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-video">
  <video loop autoplay muted>
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <p class="text">TEXTO123</p>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores ipsa sint odio culpa autem natus aliquid minus tempore quae nisi?</p>
```